# Test Dao layer with queries stored in properties file

Tags: java, testing, spring-jdbc

I'm developing REST App for the IT courses. One of the requirements was to use Spring-JDBC with all queries to be stored in separate properties file. Here is a part of my UserDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/user_queries.properties")
@Log
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    
    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
    private final RowMapper<User> rowMapper;
    
    @Value("${find.by_id}")
    private String findById;

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findById(int id) {
        SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource("id", id);
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = template.queryForObject(findById, param, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            String.format("User with id - %d, not found.", id);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(user);
    }
    
}
```

All method work fine, but troubles started when I wrote my Test to this class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestDBConfiguration.class})
public class UserDaoTest {
    
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Test
    public void findByIdTest() {
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        UserRowMapper userMapper = new UserRowMapper();
        UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImpl(template, userMapper);
        User user = new User(1, "John", "Doe",
                "$2a$04$MzVXtd4o0y4DOlyHMMLMDeE4/eezrsT5Xad.2lmGr/NkCpwBgvn3e",
                "jdoe@gmail.com", true);
        assertEquals(Optional.of(user), userDao.findById(1));
    }

}
```

When I run this Test my **findById** is always null. Is there any way to run this test and keep all queries inside the separate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `UserDaoImpl` uses Spring annotations (`@Value`, `@PropertySource`, etc), you have to initialize it via Spring to enable their injection. Or else you'd have to supply all these values yourself manually.

So in your test you should inject the DAO itself:

```
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
```

Or if you want to go manual way (not recommended), allow setting field `findById` via constructor (recommended) same way you're passing `template, userMapper`.

Comment: My mentor suggested me to add `UserDaoImpl.class`  to `@SpringBootTest` classes list, but it can't find `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` bean in my app.

Comment: It's weird that he's asking you to add it to test context (not to production one), but I don't know his plans.. Anyway, all the dependencies of your Spring beans (like NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) have to also be defined as beans. Same way your DataSource is defined.

Comment: So, the proper way is to create `@Bean` of **UserDao**  and autowire it in the test class?

Comment: That's right. In practice some of the beans that we test accept a lot of parameters in the constructor. It would be painful to create them manually in tests. Also, Spring may apply some additional processing to these beans via AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming), so the end result is not the same as just creating objects via `new`. So if you use `new`, then you can't always be confident your code is going to work same way in real life.

Comment: I just added `@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestDBConfiguration.class, UserDaoImpl.class})` and created beans of `UserRowMapper` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. All works fine =)